# Jenkins container running but not accessible via host

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I have installed jenkins on a VM and it is showing as up and running but not accessible via host.

Below is the command for running jenkins:

```
docker pull jenkins
docker run -p 9080:9080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins
```

I tried accessing via:

http://10.34.38.100:9080

[image: session]

That did not work though: what would be the right URL to access Jenkins?

Comment: jenkins is exposing 8080 so you have to map 8080 on your desired port 9080 (or 8080) like this: -p 9080:8080. After that you can check the answer of VonC

Comment: thanks..this solved our issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your VM (VMWare? VirtualBox) and host (the actual OS which has installed a VM)

IF you are using [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/), it would use the HyperV VM (Windows 10 only), and http://localhost:8080 would work.
Same idea with Docker for Mac, and its XHyve Hypervisor.

But with an actual VM, you might need to setup a **[port forwarding](https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/)** before being able to do http://localhost:8080, or to use the IP of the VM itself (for example `docker-machine ip default` 192.168.99.100).

And that supposes your Jenkins application publishes its port to the one you want, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294144/jenkins-container-running-but-not-accessible-via-host/48294202#comment83574447_48294144) by [lvthillo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4525448/lvthillo): `-p 9080:8080`.
See [`docker run` publish port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p-expose).

Every Localhost having some IP address, So If you use docker in windows by **Docker ToolBox at the Don't Check with Localhost:8080** in your browser why because that is not the actual host.Your Localhost running in Vmware so you can check your IP address by using this Command (**docker-machine ip default**)

For Example : 
   I got **192.168.99.100**  - using this IP to run the Jenkins like **192.168.99.100:8080**

Comment: Hi,  I've installed it on Ubuntu in VMWare. Have selected Bridged adapter in port forwarding. Still, this is not connecting.

Comment: @TanyaC is still not connecting using which IP address? (see https://superuser.com/a/571210/141) Or in the same page https://superuser.com/a/726147/141.